# Promise Rejection Executed but Not Thrown (Unhandled Promise Rejection)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm brand new submitting questions. I've had a good look at all the other questions that have been submitted and struggling to find a similar issue to what I have. If there is a similar question, my apologies.

I've having issues with a very basic Promise I created for this question, where I need to reject a array loop where one iteration is the same:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var promise = array.forEach(n => {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (n == 5) return reject();
    return resolve();
  });
});

Promise.all(promise).then(() => {
  console.log('true');
}).catch(() => {
  console.log('false');
});
```

When console logging each iteration, the rejection gets called but doesn't catch in the promise and I can't fathom why. I've spent almost 3 hours finding out the reasoning behind this.

Comment: Your code logs `false` for me, meaning it catches properly.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris depends on how you defined `catches property`. It catches the error that `undefined` is passed to `Promise.all` but it does not catch the `reject()` that is done for the `n==5` case.

Comment: Never use `.forEach`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything, thus `promise` is `undefined`. What you should use instead is [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Also note that you actually have to return the newly created promises:

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var promise = array.map(n => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (n == 5) return reject();
    return resolve();
  });
});

Promise.all(promise).then(() => {
  console.log('true');
}).catch(() => {
  console.log('false');
});
```

You could even write it like this:

```
var promise = array.map(n => new Promise((resolve, reject) => (n == 5) ? reject() : resolve()));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've used both .map() and .forEach() but they give me completely reverse results. After looking at your code, you're correct. I didn't return the promise and resulted as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you catch an error you should properly log it, and not just log `false` or something like that.

So if you write `console.error(err);` instead of `console.log('false')`, then you would get the error that's something like `TypeError: "can't convert undefined to object"` or `TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined` for the line with the `Promise.all(promise)`. And that should give you the hint that `promise` does not hold an array with Promises but `undefined`.

The `promise` is `undefined` because [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not return anything. What you are looking for is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The curly bracket around your `new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})` prevent that the `new Promise` is returned, so either add a `return` in front of the `new Promise` or remove those curly bracket.

And you should always reject with an actual error, otherwise you won't be able to get a proper stack trace for the error.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var promise = array.map(n => 
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (n == 5) return reject(new Error('rejected for n==5'));
    return resolve();
  })
)

Promise.all(promise).then(() => {
  console.log('true');
}).catch(err => {
  console.error(err);
});
```